# PHP - Time based math

Tags: php, date, datetime

How exactly is this done? There's so many questions on stack-overflow about what I'm trying to do; However all of the solutions are to edit the MYSQL Query, and I need to do this from within PHP.

I read about the strtotime('-30 days') method on another question and tried it, but I can't get any results. Here's what I'm trying:

```
$current_date = date_create();
$current_date->format('U');
... mysql code ...
$transaction_date = date_create($affiliate['Date']);
$transaction_date->format('U');
if($transaction_date > ($current_date - strtotime('-30 days'))) {
} else if(($transaction_date < (($current_date) - (strtotime('-30 days')))) 
             && ($transaction_date > (($current_date) - (strtotime('-60 days'))))) {
}
```

Effectively, I'm trying to sort all of the data in the database based on a date, and if the database entry was posted within the last 30 days, I want to perform a function, then I want to see if the database entry is older than 30 days, but not older than 60 days, and perform more actions.

This epoch math is really weird, you'd think that getting the epoch of the current time, the epoch of the data entry, and the epoch of 30 and 60 days ago would be good enough to do what I wanted, but for some reason it's not working, everything is returning as being less than 30 days old, even if I set the date in the database to last year.

Comment: `date_create(date(...))` is utterly pointless. You're making PHP take the current timestamp from `time()`, format it to a string `date(...)` then parse it BACK to a timestamp/object with date_create. All you need is `date_create()` if you want "now".

Comment: Alright, thanks for the information, but I'm still confused on the math part.

Comment: "I need to do this from within PHP"? Why? If you're MySQL querying, *use mysql's date filters* to get your range. Unless you can come up with a really solid reason for being unable to do so (and if you can query mysql, you're able to do so just fine) there is no reason to try to force a square peg through a round hole.

Comment: I still would suggest using epoch time for this. Can you show the epoch time code?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Because I'm using all of the data in the table, but only doing a certain task with data that falls within a time range. I could do this with two queries, but isn't it always best to minimize queries when possible?

Comment: @Christian.tucker You could/should still use MySQL to sort the dates and perhaps even add a calculated field that you can use in PHP to determine which functionality to apply to the record.

Comment: @Christian.tucker not really, you can query-as-temporary-table the full data, and then subquery the temporary table for a near instant sorted result of only the data you need for your date-range work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to convert to unix timestamp, you can already compare `DateTime` objects:

```php
$current_date = data_create();
$before_30_day_date = date_create('-30 day');
$before_60_day_date = date_create('-60 day');
$transaction_date = date_create($affiliate['Date']);

if ($transaction_date > $before_30_day_date) {
    # transation date is between -30 day and future
} elseif ($transaction_date < $before_30_day_date && $transaction_date > $before_60_day_date) {
    # transation date is between -60 day and -30 day
}
```

Comment: Even though Marc answered first and provided the explanation on why it wasn't working, you provided a working example of code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This creates (inefficiently, see my comment above) an object:

```
$current_date = date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

From which you try to subtract an integer:

```
if($transaction_date > ($current_date - strtotime('-30 days'))) {
```

which is basically

```
if (object > (object - integer))
```

which makes no sense.

you're mixing the oldschool `time()` system, which deals purely with unix timestamps, and the newer DateTime object system, which deals with objects.

What you should have is

```
$current_date = date_create(); // "now"

$d30 = new DateInterval('P30D'); // 30 days interval

$transaction_date = date_create($affiliate['Date']);

if ($transaction_date > ($current_date->sub($d30)) { ... }
```

Comment: when performing $current_date->sub does this only perform and return the math, or is it actually subtracting 30 from the date, leaving $current_date at 30 days less? I'm asking, because I need to know if I have to add 30 days back to $current_date before performing my next calculation. Thanks for the explanation on how I was using objects, it makes sense as to why it wasn't working when it's put like that.

Comment: it returns the modified time value as a new object, and doesn't touch the original. If you need to modify the original, then you'd have to do `$d = $d->sub($interval)`.

Comment: @MarcB: not true, method `sub()` changes the original object. So he will need to add back 30 days, to return date to current date...

Comment: Wait, what? Conflicting information. I'll just test it.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (P30d)

Comment: @Christian.tucker: change `P30d` to `P30D`. See my demo.

Comment: Your demo uses `'P30d'`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider `DatePeriod` class, which in essence gives you the ability to deal with a seires of DateTime objects at specified intervals.

```
$current_date = new DateTime();
$negative_thirty_days = new DateInterval::createFromDateString('-30 day');
$date_periods = new DatePeriod($current_date, $negative_thrity_days, 3);
$thirty_days_ago = $date_periods[1];
$sixty_day_ago = $date_periods[2];
```

Here you would use `$thirty_days_ago`, `$sixty_days_ago`, etc. for your comparisons.

Just showing this as alternative to other options (which will work) as this is more scalable if you need to work with a larger number of interval periods.